# Special case of Pieri-Rule

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory, symmetric-polynomials, young-tableaux

is there an "elementary" (read: short combinatorial) proof for the rule
$$ s_\lambda \cdot s_{(1)} = \sum_{\mu} s_{\mu} $$
where $\mu$ ranges over all partitions obtained from $\lambda$ by adding a singe box?

Where the Schur-polynomial $s_\lambda$ is defined as the sum over all monomials one gets from semi-standard tableaux corresponding to the Young-diagram of $\lambda$.
The number of variables here is $n$ and $\lambda$ is a partition of $d\leq n-1$.

Basically, I would like to understand Schur-Weyl duality, that is, the decomposition of the d-fold tensor product as described in chapter 6 of Fulton, Harris "Representation theory".
So alternatively, if $W(\lambda)$ if the irreducible representation of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ corresponding to $\lambda$, then I want to understand the decomposition of $W(\lambda) \otimes \mathbb{C}^n$.

$\dim W(\lambda)$ is the number of semistandard tableaux filled with numbers from $[n]$.
The identity to be proved would then be
$$ \dim W(\lambda) \cdot n = \sum_{\mu} \dim W(\mu) $$

Comment: Hmm, so this certainly follows easily from the Littlewood-Richardson rule, but while that can be proven combinatorially, it is hardly short.

Comment: Well my formula is a special case of the Pieri-formula, which is a special case of the Littlewood-Richardson rule. I was hoping this special case might be easier to prove than the complete Pieri-formula, especially since I only need to show it for the dimensions, ie setting all variables to 1.

Comment: Hmm, this is probably all contained in the chapter on symmetric functions in Stanley's book (in vol. 2). He works with an infinite number of variables, but as far as I recall, he does consider what happens when you evaluate the first variables in $1$ and the rest in $0$ which is what you are looking for.

Comment: See Exercise 2.66 (and its solution) in Vic Reiner's and my notes on *Hopf algebras in combinatorics* ( https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.8356v4 ; solutions are in an ancillary file). That gives a combinatorial proof of the whole Pieri rule based merely on the tableau-theoretic definition of the Schur functions. (Of course, the proof is not new, and in particular is sketched in Stanley.)